# Google Sheets - How to scrape data from hundreds of urls

Tags: google-sheets

I recently decided to update my spreadsheet of games I need to complete. In order to ensure my data was constantly up to date I made use of the IMPORTXML function but with the amount of urls I have begun to encounter 'loading' issues.

This is the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdcsIf9Upn_0zqTFyLAm1TMMFu_MpyTEm23EU0nVaTA/edit?usp=sharing

(Columns B,E,G and I are usually hidden)

Column A is the url.
Column B scrapes the image url and column C displays it.
Columns D,E,G and I scrape the data I want and displays it in columns D,F,H and J.

If my aim is to have upwards of 500 urls, is this something that can be only be accomplished with a script?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you are encountering the [limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) of Google services. That quota is reached by aggregating the usage of all documents and projects. Also please be aware that there could be more than one import inside the same document, like one per every cell in your example.

To diminish that usage you could modify old documents so they don't refresh anymore (commenting out the relevant pieces and deactivating triggers). Alternatively you could just delete them. If you plan to run large amounts of imports, you could use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch). Although this option is limited by the same quota discussed above, you could programmatically control when and how much to import in order to optimise your utilisation of Google services.